# What is the work of a Murdhabhishikta (BrahmKshatriya) caste?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti

What is the work of a Murdhabhishikta (BrahmKshatriya) caste ?

Murdhabhishikta - Child born from Brahmin Father and Kshatriya mother.

Can he become a priest ?

I think he can become priest or officiate any yagya but he can't accept daan as he is born from Kshatriya woman.

Answer (score 3):

Such a son is a Brahmin. So it seems he can adopt the occupations that are prescribed for a Brahmin.

[Manu Smriti 10.6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201739.html#comparative-notes) says:

> स्त्रीष्वनन्तरजातासु द्विजैरुत्पादितान् सुतान् ।
>  सदृशानेव
> तानाहुर्मातृदोषविगर्हितान् ॥ ६ ॥
>
> strīṣvanantarajātāsu dvijairutpāditān sutān |
>  sadṛśāneva
> tānāhurmātṛdoṣavigarhitān || 6 ||
>
> The sons begotten by twice-born men on wives of the next lower castes,
> they declare to be equal, tainted as they are by the defect of their
> mothers.—(6)

On the same page we find quotes from Dharmasutras of Baudhayana:

> Baudhāyana (1.16.7-12, 16; 1.17.7, 8, 11-14).—‘Sons born of wives of
> the second or third lower castes are Ambaṣṭhas, Ugras and Niṣādas. Of
> females wedded in the inverse order are born Āyogavas, Māgadhas,
> Vaiṇas, Kṣattṛs, Pulkasas, Kukkuṭas, Vaidehakas and Caṇḍālas. An
> Ambaṣṭha begets on a woman of the first caste, a Śvapāka; an Ugra on a
> woman of the second caste, a Vaiṇa; a Niṣāda on a woman of the third
> caste, a Pulkasa; in the contrary case, a Kukkuṭaka is produced. I may
> quote the following—“Those sons whom an uninitiated man begets, the
> wise call Vrāṭyas, who are excluded from the Śāvitrī.” **A Brāhmana
> begets on a woman of the Ksatriya caste, a Brāhmaṇa;** on a woman of
> the Vaiśya caste, an Ambaṣṭha; on a woman of the Śūdra caste, a
> Niṣāda,—according to some, a Pāraśava. A Kṣatriya begets on a female
> of the Vaiśya caste, a Kṣatriya; on a female of the Śūdra caste, an
> Ugra. A Vaiśya begets on a female of the Śūdra caste, a Rathakāra. A
> Śūdra begets on a female of the Vaiśya caste, a Magadha; on a female
> of the Kṣatriya caste, a Kṣattṛ; but on a female of the Brāhmaṇa
> caste, a Caṇḍāla. A Vaiśya begets on a female of the Kṣatriya caste,
> an Āyogava; on a female of the Brāhmaṇa caste, a Sūta. If among these
> a n Ambaṣṭha male and an Ugra female unite, their son shall be born in
> the regular order; if a Kṣattṛ male and a Vaidehaka female unite the
> son born shall be in the inverse order. An Ugra begets on a female of
> the Kṣattṛ caste, a Śvapāka; a Vaidehaka on a female of the Ambaṣṭha
> caste, a Vaiṇa; a Niṣāda on a female of the Śūdra caste, a Pulkasa; a
> Śūdra on a woman of the Niṣāda caste, a Kukkuṭaka.—The wise declare
> that those sprung from an intermixture of castes are Vrātyas.’

Comment: Is there anything written that he can't accept daan ? In Mbh serial starplus , Dronacharya had said that sons of Rishi Bhardwaj don't accept daan. ( Rishi Bhardwaj married only a ksatriya woman Susheela). ( Not sure if it is written in some book or not) This is why Drona didn't accept Gurudakshina from Pandavs and Kauravs but instead asked them a specific thing i.e. to defeat Drupad.

Comment: I don't know about that. But if his caste is Brahmin then he should be allowed to do everything that a Brahmin is allowed @river

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per the Āpastamba Dharma-Sūtra [Praśna II, Paṭala 6, Khaṇḍa 13], only the son begotten from a wife of equal caste may follow their father's profession.

> प्रश्न २, षठः पटल, [खण्ड १३](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.485587/page/n237/mode/2up?view=theater)
>
> सवर्णापूर्वशास्त्रविहितायां यथतु गच्छतः पुत्रास्तेषां कर्मभिस्सम्बन्धः ॥१॥
>
> > 1. Sons begotten by a man who approaches in the proper season a woman of equal caste, who has not belonged to another man, and who has been married legally, **have a right to (follow) the occupations (of their castes).**
>
> Translation by [Georg Bühler](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra/d/doc116277.html)

---

### Therefore, to answer the question asked:

### `Can he (a Murdhabhishikta/BrahmKshatriya) become a priest?`

#### No.

Purely basis the Āpastamba Dharma-Sūtra, a Murdhabhishikta/BrahmKshatriya cannot become a priest